# How can I assign a dynamic range (of rows) to a checkbox in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a workbook in excel and using activeX checkboxes to hide/unhide some rows each time as a way to enable or disable them. For that I use VBA code. However in that code I specify a static range of rows. The problem is that if I insert a new row, everything is  now offset and i have to manually rewrite all the intervals. Is there a way to do this dynamically.

Here is the code I use for two consecutive checkboxes:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

If CheckBox1 = True Then

    [24:41].EntireRow.Hidden = False

    Else: [24:41].EntireRow.Hidden = True

End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()

If CheckBox2 = True Then

    [42:49].EntireRow.Hidden = False

    Else: [42:49].EntireRow.Hidden = True

End If

End Sub
```

I have searched for a while before asking the question, and I apologise if there is an answer somewhere, I'm a total newbie to excel and VBA and I don't think I can adapt a solution that is remotely similar to the problem I'm facing.
Thanks for your precious help in advance.

Comment: I would say this depends on how you pick those rows.  Are there headers or something dictating that those rows will be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a Column in which you write an X in each row you want to hide / unhide.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1 = True Then
        For each c in Range("A1:A50")
            If c.Value = "x" Then
                c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next c
    Else
        For each c in Range("A1:A50")
            If c.Value = "x" Then
                c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next c
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I will use this solution. I'll filtter based on the number of the row in each section. Eg: To hide the first section, I'll choose the rows with 1.1 and 1.2 etc... based on the first caracter.

Answer (score 0):

You could try naming your range

```
thisworkbook.names.add name:="mydinamicrange" ,ReferstoR1C1:="Sheet1!R24c1:R49C10"
```

Then , you may use it with something like this  :

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

If CheckBox1 = True Then

    thisworkbook.names("mydinamicrange").referstorange.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    Else:  thisworkbook.names("mydinamicrange").referstorange.EntireRow.Hidden= True

End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. However, I do not know if this range will automatically expand if I add a line to it. The goal of this file is to be as generic as possible and to later be used as template and adapt if to each project, that's why i want to enable/disable (i.e: hiding ) sections.

Comment: Hi , well I did a couple of tests and it worked fine since the "name" adapts to new rows , did you try it?

Comment: Hi. I did not. Instead, I used a string comparison between the first caracter of the first cell (correspond to the section, eg: 1.12 -> 1 or 2.4 -> 2 ) If the number matches that of the section I want to hide, I hide the entire row.